# Why is the bottom of the Mariana Trench not frozen?

Tags: thermodynamics, pressure, temperature, water, geophysics

I have found following information on Wikipedia:

> The temperature is $1$ to $4\,°\mathrm C$ and the pressure is about $0.156$ GPa.

The Graph tells us that it's liquid.
However, I don't quite understand why the temperature is not below $0\,°\mathrm C$. Light is unable to reach these depths and thus unable to transfer heat.

My reasoning is that eventually particles with higher kinetic energy will have risen due to convection, lowering the temperature below $0\,°\mathrm C$, resulting in freezing the water.

[image]

Comment: The ground could be hot at places due to magma.

Comment: but lets suppose a more general case where we assume that there is no magma

Comment: If oceans spontaneously separated into a hot part at the top and a cold part at the bottom, we could use that to build a perpetual motion machine.

Comment: @JohnRennie You could start with a block of water at (say) 20 degrees, wait for it to separate, then run a heat engine with the 40 degree water as the hot side and the 0 degree water as the cold side. Repeat until the water gets to 0 degrees. This violates the Second Law of Thermodynamics.

Comment: @JohnRennie Oh so it spontaneously cools down by itself? That violates the *First* Law of Thermodynamics.

Comment: @user253751 I think this doesn't really apply for an open system

Comment: @AlessioPopovic Well the surroundings are all at about 20°C as well, so where would the energy go to?

Comment: @user253751 Now I'm thinking that this only works if we are talking about larger depths. As a mater of fact water is more dense at the bottom then at the surface. which implies there is greater entropy at the surface resulting in a difference of temperature. I am not saying that its notable for lets say a bathtub. However it is when it comes to the ocean.

Comment: @user253751 It''s called a [thermocline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermocline).  It's also not really "spontaneous".  People _do_ run heat engines off it [(OTEC)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ocean_thermal_energy_conversion).

Comment: The graph in this question pertains to pure water. Ocean water freezes at about -2° C; the exact temperature depends on salinity and pressure.

Comment: It might be geothermal energy that prevents it from freezing.

Comment: @ManvendraSomvanshi I'm not sure that this is necessarily the case. There are regions in the ocean with very little geothermal activities and water doesn't seem to freeze there

Comment: I'm surprised no one's mentioned the latitude of the trench (which is near the Phillipines), but, as my education was acquired in the same state (Florida) where Trump acquired his, maybe I shouldn't be....

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are basically asking why water does not freeze at the bottom of the trench. It is basically because of two reasons:

1. it is very important to understand the difference between fresh and salt water. We are talking about salt water here and the freezing point (phase change) is below $0^\circ \,\rm{C}$, at around $-2^\circ \,\rm{C}$. This takes your question as to why water at the bottom of the trench cannot reach $-2^\circ \,\rm{C}$.
2. you are asking about the bottom of the trench, where the water is in direct contact with the ground. To reach freezing (phase change), the ground would need to have the same (or even colder) $-2^\circ \,\rm{C}$. In reality, because of geothermal energy, the ground is way warmer then that.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Answer (score 3):

Your intuition is that warm water rises, so eventually the coldest water molecules end up at the bottom and freeze. There are two problems with this:

(1) individual water molecules do not really feel much of buoyancy if they move fast (=are hot). The buoyancy of warm fluids and gases is because warm molecules bounce more vigorously against each other, producing an expansion of the medium that lowers its density and this makes it tend to move upwards if it is surrounded by colder, more dense medium. So there will not be any strong sorting of molecules, just of water parcels.

(2) Water conducts heat, and a cold water parcel surrounded by warmer water or rock will tend to heat up. This is the main reason the deepest ocean is not arbitrarily cold. There is some heat coming from the upper warmer layers even if they do not mix, and there is geothermal heat (around 60 mW/m$^2$) from below.

There are further issues. There are slow currents (the thermohaline circulation) driven by the polar regions dripping cold, salty water into the deep, and upwellings in some regions where the deep water gets mixed with warm surface waters.

Finally, the pressure at the deepest trenches is still somewhat below the level where high-pressure ice would form. Were the trenches deeper we would actually get ice formation down there up until the level where the pressure was insufficient. This is fairly temperature-independent (the upper curve between blue and green is fairly horizontal), so it would mostly depend on depth.

(Note that in the uppermost atmosphere where the density is low enough molecules actually do show some sorting since they do not collide much, and the hottest molecules go on long parabolic arcs.)

Comment: @DavidHammen - Yes, I see that the mention of the temperature dependency is incorrect. I have removed that statement, which did not affect the main answer.

Answer (score 1):

Frozen water is less dense than the liquid water, so when icicles are formed, they are moving up, so the ice always builds up at the top of a body of water. If the water reservoir is deep, then, because of thermal capacity of a large volume of water it does not get frozen completely from top to bottom.
The ocean water does not get frozen to the bottom because of many underwater streams moving warm water from one part of the world to the other. Gulfstream is one example of such streams.

Comment: This answer seems consistent with the relatively small (for whatever latitude) seasonal variations in temperature that characterize coastal areas and islands, as well as with the well-known "turning over" of pond and lake water in autumn.

Answer (score 0):

The water down there does not freeze because of [freezing point dpression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freezing-point_depression),
plus the effect of the pressure (In order to freeze water needs to expand).
Since it is not frozen it keeps mixing up with the water coming from above.

Comment: That doesn't mean that water is unable to reach temperatures below $0\,°\mathrm C$

Comment: im not entirely sure anymore if the guy is trolling or serious...the densest water goes to the bottom Alessio. And the densest water is 1°C to 4°C as wikipedia states (according to you) that that is the temperature at the bottom of the trench.

Comment: @SomeGuy normal ice (not the one that forms under high pressure) is less dense than water. Is not water density at low temperature the problem, but the transition from liquid to solid state that requires expansion, so, yes pressure could in some circumstances prevent the transition.

Comment: @FluidCode From where do you get the notion that ice is less dense than water at *this* pressure? Because the phase diagram does not show that. No transition from liquid to solid does not necessarily 'take space'. That is a specific characteristic of water, that becomes less dense when freezing! It expands. Same mass, higher volume, thus less density. Liquid metal for example will not show this behaviour. It will decrease in volume upon freezing, thus it will harden under pressure *or* upon cooling. At high enough pressures, even water will do so. But not at pressures as low as in the trench .